# Store argparse input to use as variable

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to require input from the user for a hardware id to then be called later on, I cannot work out how to get it so the user types

`<command> --id <id>`

Please help me see where I'm going wrong! Thanks

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Return a list of useful information after specifying a hardare/asset ID')
parser.add_argument('--id', type=str, required=True, help ='A hardware/asset id to provide information on')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
args = parser.parse_args()

def main():
    hardware_id = hardware_id_input
    host = get_host_information(hardware_id)
    print(host["hostname"])
    print(host["hardware_id"])
```

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args()` … `args.id`…?!

Comment: @deceze sorry. forgot to mention in the main post that im fairly new and not too sure whats right/wrong etc - I tried to originally call this and it gives another error, that being

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: You tried to call *what*?

Comment: So, I added a store_const action to the id arg, then have mentioned it in main as `hardware_id = args.id()` now getting unexpected keyword argument type error.

Comment: Stop just throwing random stuff at the wall. Your code is fine (mostly). You just need to access the arg as `args.id`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the call to vars. You would have your argument stored as args.id after parsing. You would then call your main with the args.id as input.

Edit: added a code sample

```
def main(hw_id):
    print(hw_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description.')
    parser.add_argument('--id', type=str, help='The hardware id.', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.id)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, forgot to mention that i'm extremely new to python and trying to jsut get to grips with making something - the call to vars has been removed and then changed action to store_const and then called it in main as hardware_id = args.id and it throws up a whole new __init__ error unexpected keyword argument 'type'

Comment: I edited the answer to include a working code.